# Export data on sql developer without depending on the Database name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im making an export of data on sql developer, and im getting the database name or user name before every table, like this:

```
Insert into FAUSTO.CLIENT (ID, Name) ...
```

So the database in this case is FAUSTO. I want this export to be independent of database name.
I have another script that creates the schema and then i run some scripts that inserts data. So, no matter the database name, it should work always.

Thanks

Comment: That's the schema (which is the same as the user), not the database name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is slightly unintuitive, but in the SQL Developer Export Wizard, uncheck the 'Show schema' option from the Export DDL section, *before* unticking that whole section.

[image: Export Wizard dialog]

The insert statements honour that setting even if you exclude the DDL.

With that turned off the generated script looks like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - Thursday-June-23-2016   
--------------------------------------------------------
REM INSERTING into A
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into A (NAME,AGE) values ('Tom',1);
Insert into A (NAME,AGE) values ('John',2);
...
```

If I export again but leave that 'show schema' checkbox on instead I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - Thursday-June-23-2016   
--------------------------------------------------------
REM INSERTING into STACKOVERFLOW.A
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into MYSCHEMA.A (NAME,AGE) values ('Tom',1);
Insert into MYSCHEMA.A (NAME,AGE) values ('John',2);
...
```